# Mapping a functor to another in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

I have a function that produces a `Maybe a` type and I'm using it in a function to produce an `Either b a`. Is there a way I can map `Nothing` to `Left x` to simplify my code? The following code gives some context:

```
rmX :: ... -> Maybe a
cvX :: ... -> Either CVXError a
data CVXError = BadIndex | NoCover | NoSpace
cvX ... =
  ...
  case rmx 1 xs of
    Nothing -> Left NoSpace
    Just p  -> Right (x2:x1:(fromJust (rmX (-1) p)))
-- given that rmX always passes on negative value arg
```

The case statement is just begging to be replaced with `fmap` but the problem is that I'm not sure how to 'map' `Nothing` to `Left NoSpace` in an `fmap` call or to even extract this pattern to make my own util function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) function:

```
cvX ... =
  ...
  maybe (Left NoSpace) (\p -> Right (x2:x1:(fromJust (rmX (-1) p)))) $
    rmX 1 xs
```

Answer (score 4):

In this context, it is worth mentioning the [*errors*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.3) package. It offers a number of functions for juggling `Maybe`, `Either` and related types, including [`note`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.3/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:note), which "[tags] the `Nothing` value of a `Maybe`":

```
note :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
```

```
cvX ... =
  ...
  note NoSpace $ fmap (\p -> x2:x1:(fromJust (rmX (-1) p))) (rmX 1 xs)
```

Unsurprisingly, the implementation of `note` uses `maybe` exactly like Sebastian Redl's answer does.

P.S.: It is always a little unpleasant to use `fromJust`, given how it fails when given `Nothing`. If `rmX (-1)` cannot produce a `Nothing`, you might want to consider factoring out a separate function that doesn't return `Maybe a` to be used instead of `fromJust (rmX (-1) p)`.

Answer (score 0):

One similar option is to use the `Maybe` monad until the very end, then apply `Left` or `Right` as necessary with `maybe`.

```
maybe (Left NoSpace) Right $ do
     p1 <- rmX 1 xs
     p2 <- rmX (-1) p1
     return (x2:x1:p2)
```

There's lots of room for tweaking this, depending on your preference for `do` notation vs `>>=`:

```
-- untested; take these with a grain of salt...

maybe (Left NoSpace) Right $ do
    p <- rmX 1 xs >>= rmX (-1) 
    return (x2:x1:p)

maybe (Left NoSpace) Right (rmX 1 xs >>= rmX (-1) >>= (return . (x1:)) >>= (return . (x2:)))

-- etc
```